# SharePoint Refiner webpart only showing one filter item instead of three

Tags: c#, search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am building an out of the box SharePoint search. The basic search works just fine.

I have created a SharePoint list and added a metadata column which is tied to the TermStore and ran the full crawl. All looks good till this point.

The problem is, I have added a Refiner web part which only shows one refiner item at a time ( either Samsung, Apple or HTC) depending on what I type in the searchbox as shown in the screenshots below.

I would like the Refiner to display all the three refiners at all times for users to select and filter their search results.

As you can see below the Refiner webpart only show the filter value that is typed in the searchbox: 
[image]
[image]

This list shows all the items. And as you can see there are three items (HTC, Apple and Samsung)in the list:
[image]

The metadata type column definition is shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

My Refiner configuration is as follows:
[image]

The Term Store can also be seen in the screenshot below:
[image]

Please reply if there is something I need to do to fix my refiners to show all the filters options for users to select ( e.g. HTC, Apple, Samsung).

Thank you.

Kind regards.

Comment: There is a [specific site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) for such kind of questions

Comment: how can i move this question to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Please search for "*" to get all available search results. You should have all refiner options available now.
Refiner is used to narrow down current search results. 
So when you search for "Samsung" you will get only "Samsung" option, because all Search Results have "AKPhones" Managed Property = "Samsung".

Comment: Yes, the filter values in the refiner are displayed when the users types the "*". How can we make the filter values show at all times without having the user to type "*" in the searchbox?

Comment: Refiners are connected with displayed results. And even when you show all hidden options from refiner, you will get 0 results if you click them. This is because refiner is a concatenation of "Query AND Refiner value". I guess that you need new box with links only to "Refiner value". You can do this with Search Navigation webpart or create new Refiner Display Template and then change it to display all possible options with new links.